# Display and hide div with button in asp

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to display some divs that contains some controls in asp.net. i want to be able to display them in a order and remove them in an order. so when i click a button that adds the div it has to get the next one in the line. And the other way around when i remove them. Here is the divs

```
<div id="AdditivesENumbers1" style="display: none" class="myRow">
                        <div class="mediumCol">
                            <div class="myRow">
                                <div class="mediumCol title">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblNewAdditivesENumbers1" runat="server" Text="Additives & E-numbers"></asp:Label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="myRow">
                                <div class="mediumCol">
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddNewAdditivesENumbers1" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="smallCol ekstraSpaceLeft">
                            <div class="myRow">
                                <div class="smallCol title">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblNewAdditivesENumbersLevelOfContainment1" runat="server" Text="Level Of Containment"></asp:Label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="myRow">
                                <div class="smallCol">
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddNewAdditivesENumbersLevelOfContainment1" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="AdditivesENumbers2" style="display: none" class="myRow ">
                        <div class="mediumCol">
                            <div class="myRow">
                                <div class="mediumCol title">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblNewAdditivesENumbers2" runat="server" Text="Additives & E-numbers"></asp:Label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="myRow">
                                <div class="mediumCol">
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddNewAdditivesENumbers2" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="smallCol ekstraSpaceLeft">
                            <div class="myRow">
                                <div class="smallCol title">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblNewAdditivesENumbersLevelOfContainment2" runat="server" Text="Level Of Containment"></asp:Label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="myRow">
                                <div class="smallCol">
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddNewAdditivesENumbersLevelOfContainment2" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="AdditivesENumbers3" style="display: none" class="myRow ">
                        <div class="mediumCol">
                            <div class="myRow">
                                <div class="mediumCol title">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblNewAdditivesENumbers3" runat="server" Text="Additives & E-numbers"></asp:Label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="myRow">
                                <div class="mediumCol">
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddNewAdditivesENumbers3" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="smallCol ekstraSpaceLeft">
                            <div class="myRow">
                                <div class="smallCol title">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblNewAdditivesENumbersLevelOfContainment3" runat="server" Text="Level Of Containment"></asp:Label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="myRow">
                                <div class="smallCol">
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddNewAdditivesENumbersLevelOfContainment3" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="AdditivesENumbers4" style="display: none" class="myRow ">
                        <div class="mediumCol">
                            <div class="myRow">
                                <div class="mediumCol title">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblNewAdditivesENumbers4" runat="server" Text="Additives & E-numbers"></asp:Label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="myRow">
                                <div class="mediumCol">
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddNewAdditivesENumbers4" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="smallCol ekstraSpaceLeft">
                            <div class="myRow">
                                <div class="smallCol title">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblNewAdditivesENumbersLevelOfContainment4" runat="server" Text="Level Of Containment"></asp:Label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="myRow">
                                <div class="smallCol">
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddNewAdditivesENumbersLevelOfContainment4" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="AdditivesENumbers5" style="display: none" class="myRow ">
                        <div class="mediumCol">
                            <div class="myRow">
                                <div class="mediumCol title">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblNewAdditivesENumbers5" runat="server" Text="Additives & E-numbers"></asp:Label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="myRow">
                                <div class="mediumCol">
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddNewAdditivesENumbers5" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="smallCol ekstraSpaceLeft">
                            <div class="myRow">
                                <div class="smallCol title">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblNewAdditivesENumbersLevelOfContainment5" runat="server" Text="Level Of Containment"></asp:Label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="myRow">
                                <div class="smallCol">
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddNewAdditivesENumbersLevelOfContainment5" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="AdditivesENumbers6" style="display: none" class="myRow ">
                        <div class="mediumCol">
                            <div class="myRow">
                                <div class="mediumCol title">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblNewAdditivesENumbers6" runat="server" Text="Additives & E-numbers"></asp:Label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="myRow">
                                <div class="mediumCol">
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddNewAdditivesENumbers6" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="smallCol ekstraSpaceLeft">
                            <div class="myRow">
                                <div class="smallCol title">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblNewAdditivesENumbersLevelOfContainment6" runat="server" Text="Level Of Containment"></asp:Label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="myRow">
                                <div class="smallCol">
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddNewAdditivesENumbersLevelOfContainment6" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="AdditivesENumbers7" style="display: none" class="myRow ">
                        <div class="mediumCol">
                            <div class="myRow">
                                <div class="mediumCol title">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblNewAdditivesENumbers7" runat="server" Text="Additives & E-numbers"></asp:Label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="myRow">
                                <div class="mediumCol">
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddNewAdditivesENumbers7" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="smallCol ekstraSpaceLeft">
                            <div class="myRow">
                                <div class="smallCol title">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblNewAdditivesENumbersLevelOfContainment7" runat="server" Text="Level Of Containment"></asp:Label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="myRow">
                                <div class="smallCol">
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddNewAdditivesENumbersLevelOfContainment7" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="AdditivesENumbers8" style="display: none" class="myRow">
                        <div class="mediumCol">
                            <div class="myRow">
                                <div class="mediumCol title">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblNewAdditivesENumbers8" runat="server" Text="Additives & E-numbers"></asp:Label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="myRow">
                                <div class="mediumCol">
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddNewAdditivesENumbers8" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="smallCol ekstraSpaceLeft">
                            <div class="myRow">
                                <div class="smallCol title">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblNewAdditivesENumbersLevelOfContainment8" runat="server" Text="Level Of Containment"></asp:Label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="myRow">
                                <div class="smallCol">
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddNewAdditivesENumbersLevelOfContainment8" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="myRow">
                        <div class="smallCol">
                            <div class="myRow">
                                <div class="smallCol">
                                    <input id="addNewAdditive" value="Add new" type="button" class="btn btn-default" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
```

When the page is loaded none of the divs can be visible. first when you click this button.

```
<div class="myRow">
                        <div class="smallCol">
                            <div class="myRow">
                                <div class="smallCol">
                                    <input id="addNewAdditive" value="CLICK" type="button" class="btn btn-default" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

is this even possible and do any of you have some ideas on how to do this?

Comment: why you don't use  `asp:Panel` ?

Comment: @zey i have never worked with asp:panel before. I will look in to that and see if it is possible to do it with that

Comment: OK , if your code of setting visibility of your div is from `server side` , i suggest you to take a look for `asp:UpdatePanel` .

Comment: have you referred jquery in you page ? if so you can use .. 
`$("[id^='AdditivesENumbers']").show();`